# A SecurityTokenHandler is not registered to read security token

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, adfs

I have a SharePoint web application with **ADFS**, when ADFS does the **authentication** web application will throw below **error**,I have tried some solution from internet but no luck.
**below is the Error**:

> ID4014: A SecurityTokenHandler is not registered to read security token ('EncryptedData', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#').
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenException:
>   ID4014: A SecurityTokenHandler is not registered to read security
>   token ('EncryptedData', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#').

Answer (score 1):

Did it work before or is it the first time you are using ADFS authentication ?

Which version of ADFS are you using ?

Is JWT enabled ? If yes, disable it and try again.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/maheshu/2015/05/26/json-web-token-jwt-support-in-adfs/

Also you can try to follow this great blog post :
https://jeremythake.com/troubleshooting-sharepoint-2013-provider-hosted-apps-on-premises-d4b5f633f48d

Please let us know.

Comment: thank you said,this is the first time.let me try those links and let you know.

Comment: Any news ? Also check the following :) https://www.helloitsliam.com/2015/01/23/sharepoint-and-adfs-with-encryption-2/

Comment: Hi sayed i asked the team to check JWT, which is the last hope.sine its from another team(ADFS) I still wait for their confirmation.I will update here.

Comment: Hi sayed i asked the team to check JWT, which is the last hope.sine its from another team(ADFS) I still wait for their confirmation.I will update here.

Comment: Please check the Certificate 100 times,Our issue was Certificate.